# Application Pool automatically disabled in IIS 7 on Windows 2008R2

Tags: iis-7

Have a web application running on several servers.  Two of the servers are having issues where the application pool becomes disabled.  Message in the Event viewer System Log:  Application pool 'xxxxx' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Just prior to this message are several other 'Warning' Messages:  A process serving application pool 'xxxxx' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1072'. The data field contains the error number.  Or A process serving application pool 'xxxxx' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3644'. The process exit code was '0x0'.

Running IIS 7.  The servers that are failing are running 2008R2 with Service Pack1 and the other are running 2008R2 (no Service Pack).

In the HTTP log right before I see the AppOffline message, there are the several Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue and Client_Reset messages.

I have read and reread many posting about changing the Rapid-Fail Protection settings from the default of failure interval (minutes) 5 and Maximum failures 5 as I can see that after five failures in five minutes the AppPool is stopped.  However, doing this just changes the number of issues during a particular time before the AppPool will be stopped and not really addressing the root cause of the problem.

What is the correct method for determine why the application is failing?
Could the difference in service pack on the server be a culprit?

Thanks.

Comment: Crash dumps might help but that's not programming related.